# How to manipulate ESI URLs at Varnish to include user specific context?

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am trying to use Varnish to cache a page that has some user specific text and links on it. The best way to cache such pages is via [Edge Side Includes](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html).

**Context**

My web application is RESTful and does not support sessions or even cookies for that matter. Every source URL is complete in a sense that it contains a user specific query parameter to be able to identify a unique user. The pages which see most visits in the web application are listing pages. I just need to show the user's email in the header and the links on the page must also carry the user specific query parameter ahead so as to simulate a logged in behavior. Page contents are supposed to be the same for each user except for the header and those internal links.

I tried to use `<esi:include />` for such areas on the page but obviously, could not include the user specific parameter in the page source (else the first user specific hit would be cached with the first user's parameter and be served the same for every subsequent user). Further, I tried to strip user specific parameter in `vcl_recv` subroutine of Varnish and store it temporarily in a header such as `req.http.X-User` just before a `lookup`. Each source URL gets hashed with a `req.url` that doesn't contain any user specific parameters and hence, does not create duplicate cache objects for each unique user.

**Question**

I would like to read the user specific parameter from `req.http.X-User` and hash user specific ESI requests by adding this user specific value against each ESI URL as a query parameter. I do not see a way in which one could share query parameters between a source request and it's included ESI requests. Could someone help?

I have tried to depict my objective in the following diagram:
[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that the ESI call itself is going to be cached. Including any query strings in the URL.

I cant remember the specifics, but I think you can get Varnish to pass cookies through the ESI requests, so you could store the value in a cookie (encrypted?) and then that can be read via whatever is handling the ESI call.

Or maybe you can get it to pass the HTTP headers through? In which case it can be read directly from the HTTP header parameter

Comment: ESI fetch is independent of the parent fetch and hence can't see the headers set during the parent fetch. So I can't receive the HTTP header, which was set during a parent fetch, in an ESI fetch. I'm looking for a solution wherein I could set parameters/headers on the ESI request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704712/varnish-and-esi-http-auth May be useful

Comment: Thanks! This is useful to some extent. However, it involves setting a fixed Authorization header. In my case, the header should inherit Authorization from a parent request itself. I'm looking into Varnish's source code to know more about allowing ESI parameters.